What should be the crowding distance of overlapping points?
When using an evolutionary algorithm like NSGA-II, we sort candidate solutions based on their domination level (rank) and their crowding distance (CD) to select the solutions that we will carry over to the next generation during evolution.
What if 2 or more extreme solutions 'overlap' and have identical fitness? Extreme solutions are generally assigned a CD of infinity.
A case where this is a problem: If the true pareto front is extremely sparse (think 3 pareto-optimal trade-offs: A, B, & C in a 3 objective problem, each representing an 'extreme'), then, often the entire population converges to the points A, B & C. In this case, it is not possible to clearly determine an order in these solutions. However, if most solutions lie on points A and B, and very few on point C, then it is possible that during selection, we completely miss points on C (as each solution is equally optimal), thus 'losing' more unique Pareto-optimal solutions.
I believe the CD metric used should account for overlapping solutions, which are common in sparse settings. If this were the case, points on C would end up being more desirable as they are more 'unique' -- something which we use CD to determine in the first place.
Any papers/practitioners that could perhaps shed some light on more appropriate metrics for such situations?
